# WS-Trust - can't receive result from WIF, Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: silverlight, ws-security, wif, claims-based-identity

I created Web App with service to receive claims  using WS-Trust  protocol for some Silverlight app.
I see claims are created in GetOutputClaimsIdentity() method (called twice-why?), but on Silverligh level I receive 'Not Found' message (empty stream?).

Silverlight support for WS-Trust I took from latest WIF Training kit. I was trying to debug code on server side,
but unfortunately WIF source code is not available as part of .NET Framework debugging yet :(

So I have no idea why it doesn't send back properly the response with claims to client app.

Content of Web.config file for WS-Trust project is below (I use self signed cert currently):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
 <configSections>
 <section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
 </configSections>

 <appSettings>
 <add key="IssuerName" value="PatientInfo"/>
 <add key="SigningCertificateName" value="CN=PatientInfo"/>
 <!--<add key="EncryptingCertificateName" value="CN=DefaultApplicationCertificate"/>-->
 <add key="EncryptingCertificateName" value=""/>
 </appSettings>

 <system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
 <assemblies>
 <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
 </assemblies>
 </compilation>
 <authentication mode="None"/>
 <authorization>
 <allow users="*"/>
 </authorization>
 </system.web>

 <system.serviceModel>

 <serviceHostingEnvironment
 aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
 multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

 <behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
 <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
 </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 <bindings>

 <ws2007HttpBinding>
 <binding name="ws2007HttpBindingConfiguration">
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
  <message establishSecurityContext="false" clientCredentialType="UserName" />
  </security>
 </binding>
 </ws2007HttpBinding>

 </bindings>

 <services>
 <service name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceContract" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
 <endpoint address="IWSTrust13"
   binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
   bindingConfiguration="ws2007HttpBindingConfiguration"
   contract="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrust13SyncContract"/>
 <host>
  <baseAddresses>
  <add baseAddress="https://WIN-8LUMNJ5E6S4/PatientHistInfo.WS-Trust/InternalAuthentication.svc" />
  </baseAddresses>
 </host>
 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
 </service>
 </services>
 </system.serviceModel>

 <microsoft.identityModel>
 <service>
 <securityTokenHandlers>
 <remove type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.WindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
 <add type="eSoft.Server.Security.CustomUserNamePasswordTokenHandler, PatientHistInfo.WS-Trust"/>
 </securityTokenHandlers>
 </service>
 </microsoft.identityModel>

 <system.diagnostics>
 <sources>
 <source name="Microsoft.IdentityModel" switchValue="Verbose">
 <listeners>
  <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="WIFTrace.txt" />
 </listeners>
 </source>
 </sources>
 <trace autoflush="true" />
 </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

Fiddler result is below:

HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Timestamp: 15:41:21.666

ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.

What can cause such issue?

Comment: Finally I found the issue. MS swallows some exceptions in Windows Identity Foundation and after turning on different exception monitoring settings (like "Break when exceptions cross Appdomain/native boundary" and similar) I found source of the problem! 


IIS_IUSRS group had no access to private key of my certificate :( 


Why there wasn't such info neither in WIF log nor Debug log window ??? It took me two days to became so desperate to start debugging on so low level. 


**MS guys - please remember about the users of your frameworks !!!**

Comment: I met a similar problem. I move my AppPool Identity from Administrators to the IIS_IUSRS group, and suddenly, my web app failed because it cannot acquire the private key of my certificate. So I moved it back to admins, and things are ok now. But according to here (http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis-7/ ), it gives me the impression that all the AppPool ID should be in the IIS_IUSRS, this is misleading!